# Change the title of ThickBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the text that appears in the ThickBox in the top panel. Right now it looks like this (HTML from Firebug):

http://test2.richardknop.com/thickbox.jpg

So I would like to change this part of the HTML:

```
<div id="TB_closeAjaxWindow">
<a id="TB_closeWindowButton" title="Close" href="#">close</a>
or Esc Key
</div>
```

To for example:

```
<div id="TB_closeAjaxWindow">
<a id="TB_closeWindowButton" title="Close" href="#">close</a>
</div>
```

I have read the documentation page for ThickBox plugin and there isn't mentioned any way to do this.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look through the javascript file that you are using for ThickBox and search for "or Esc Key" and delete it...

I don't necessarily like modifying code in those js files, but have done it before...

**EDIT**
I opened up this file: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.js and was able to find this text "or Esc Key" on line 128...

This line starts off with:

```
$("#TB_window").append("<a href='' i.....
```

Comment: it's not anywhere in the js file. I searched for "or Esc Key" and NetBeans hasn't found anything.

Comment: Entire site? The only thing that has anything to do with the ThickBox jQuery plugin is the js file. Other files are HTML templates and PHP code written by me.

Comment: Yeah it's there. I was using the compressed version of the js file and it's not there. I'm using uncompressed version now.

Comment: Richard: should not be a difference between compressed and not compressed.  The text has to be there in order to be rendered to the screen.

Comment: You need not to edit JS file, simply add modal=true in the params

Answer (score 19):

> `<a name="Set Follow Up Date" href="rikin_adhyapak.php" class="thickbox" />rikin adhyapak is an excellent PHP Coder!</a>`
>
> you can set name as title to be displayed on your popup window!

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you. Solved my problem within 1.79 seconds ;)

Comment: This solution works if you are using WordPress. Just use `name=""` in your anchor tag and it will show up as your thickbox title.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem (I was trying to remove "Esc Key") and I couldn't find it. If you search the compressed code though, you won't find "Esc Key", if you search "Esc" and "Key", you'll find them. Here's a snippet of code with the two words in:

```
goNext|**Esc**|or|close|tb_showIframe|TB_imageCount|Close|new|browser|TB_FoundURL|**Key**|Image|
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is A solution to Prevent escape key AND remove text "or Esc" from ThickBox.

```
function diableEscape(){
    var data = $("#TB_closeAjaxWindow").find("a");
    $("#TB_closeAjaxWindow").html(data);
    $(data).click(function() {
        tb_remove();
    });
    document.onkeyup = function(e){     
    };
}
```

And then call above "diableEscape();" function in open popup script.

```
$("#name").click(function(){
    tb_show("Add Name", $(this).attr("name")+"?height=400"+"&width=580&TB_iframe=true", "");
    jQuery("#TB_overlay").unbind("click",tb_remove);
    diableEscape();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: typo: you mean 'disable', not 'diable'

Answer (score 2):

The `<a>` title attribute will be append on modal title

```
<a title="Your Modal Title" href="#TB_inline?width=450px&height=250px&inlineId=modal-window-id&modal=false" class="button thickbox">Open Modal</a>

<div id="modal-window-id" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum sit dolla amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used thickbox with Wordpress, but when I dig through the code, I found this block of code -

```
if(!params['modal']){
    document.onkeyup = function(e){     
        if (e == null) { // ie
            keycode = event.keyCode;
        } else { // mozilla
            keycode = e.which;
        }
        if(keycode == 27){ // close
            tb_remove();
        }   
    };
}
```

The above code hooks the esc key functionality, only when the parameter passed is not "modal". So to hack this simply pass the modal=true in the href. Your html code will look like this -

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=440&amp;width=600&amp;inlineId=popup&amp;modal=true">Open</a>
```

You do not have to add any special function or mess around with the original JS file.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Sachin